# How can I use  similar functions across all Models in Django

Tags: django, inheritance, django-models

I have three functions which I need in every Django Model:

```
def __unicode__(self):
            return self.MODELNAME_name

def get_absolute_url(self):
            return "/MODELNAME/list/" 

def get_fields(self):
            return [(field, field.value_to_string(self)) for field in MODELNAME._meta.fields]
```

The only thing different is the `MODELNAME`

How can I use inheritance so that I use three functions in one class and other inherit from it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use multiple inheritance:

```
class CommonFunctions(object):
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.MODELNAME_name
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return "/MODELNAME/list/" 
    def get_fields(self):
        return [(field, field.value_to_string(self)) for field in MODELNAME._meta.fields]

class ZeModel(models.Model, CommonFunctions):
    [...]

x = ZeModel()
x.get_absolute_url()
```

(Make sure you replace `MODELNAME` with `self.__class__.__name__`)

I did not test this, but it should work.

Comment: By replacing the MODELNAME u mean like this     `return "/self.__class__.__name__/list/" `

Comment: I mean `return "/{0}/list/".format(self.__class__.__name__)`... I thought that was obvious

Comment: sorry for  that , i am newbie in python and django

Comment: sorry again, above one worked but this didn't worked `format(self.__class__.__name__)._meta.fields`

Answer (score 0):

You don't need anything at all. `self` already refers to the relevant class.

Comment: Sorry but i could not understood , u mean to say that where i am using `MODELNAME` , i can use `self` there. Currently i am not using inheritance so can i declare all that in one class and extend others from it

Answer (score 0):

Daniel's answer is right. But if you want a string, that is the name of the current model, you can use:

```
self._meta.verbose_name_raw
```